# How to retrieve number from string between "o=" and "&" characters in Ecxel?

Tags: excel, string

I was surfing the net, looking for a solution on how to retrieve the number that I need from a string in Excel.
So I have this kinda string:

> "somecharacterso=3242&morecharacters"

and I am trying to retrieve the "3242" number according to this https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-regex-formulas/#functions

and stuck with this RegExp: `o=\b(\d+)\b&` but it extracts the full substring not the number only.

Comment: Show your code please. Are you retrieving the submatch? How are you using the regex object? Also, you don't need to use regex perse if you want to avoid vba.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry I probably specified bad, I need a number between  "o=" and "&" characters, the "o" character is part of the task, it's not a random string. So I have the next strings: "RANDOMSTRINGo=3242&NEXTSTRING"

Comment: @DanChernenko so check out the edited answer, only needed a little tweak. And I still assume that you ONLY want the n umber as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's good style in Excel formulae as well as in programming languages, particularly for making the logic easily understandable to other people who use the file later.
So if the starting data is in A2:
In B2 put `=FIND("o=",A2)`
In C2 put `=FIND("&",A2)`
In D2 put `=MID(A2,B2+2,C2-B2-2) * 1`
Exactly the same logic as Solar Mike's answer, but for most people easier to follow, check, and amend if necessary in the future.
Formulae using native Excel functions (especially shortish ones) are understood by far more people than regex.

Answer (score 1):

So, now tested and improved:

EDIT: based on comment to use "o=" and "&":

```
=MID(A1,FIND("o=",A1,1)+2,(FIND("&",A1,1)-FIND("o=",A1,1)-2))*1
```

Does exactly as asked.

```
=mid(A1,find("=",A1,1)+1,find("&",A1,1)-(find("=",A1,1)+1))*1
```

returns the 3242 as a number.

[image]